# Take screenshot of views with view.layer.cornerRadius

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to take a screenshot:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentView.frame.size);
[contentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self,@selector(savedImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
```

The problem with this is that it seems not to capture my `UILabel's` correctly that I have with rounded corners.

```
lbl.layer.cornerRadius=radius;
```

This is how it should be:

[image]

and this is how it appears when the view is captured:

[image]

Whats goin on?? I've tried a combination of `maskToBounds` and `clipsToBounds` but nothing is working, maybe there is an alternate way that can capture the view with rounded corners.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: if its any symbol you want to add to the label, you can try with unicode.

Comment: How did you manage to get a diamond out of a label by rounding it's corners? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Desdenova the corner radius was very high, try it out

Comment: I did, that was my first thought. Because it looks like it is inside out. But couldn't have the same result some how. You don't see it like that because you are masking the layer to it's bounds, seems `renderInContext:` disregards that property. You should really replace your diamond I think.

Comment: yeah, this question is old, since then I just used a picture instead

Comment: Ah my bad. Someone bumped it to the front page and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the **bounds** of your view  while initialising your **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext**.

For Ex:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0); //retina res
```

Comment: 1.0 scale is not retina resolution.